# Android studio using edittext for dialing

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialer

I created in my xml an `EditText` and a `Button`.

What I'm trying to do in the java is to let the user enter a number, then press the button and then i want the dialer to open with the input.

Is there a way to do it?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is!

You need to add a `ClickListener` to your `Button` and start the call intent:

```
dialButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
           if (numTxt != null && (numTxt.getText().length()>0)) {// you can add other conditions if you want
              startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + numTxt.getText())));
           }
      }
});
```

PS:

- *dialButton* is your `Button` and *numTxt*  is your `EditText`
- [This](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/simple-dialer-application/) is a simple tutorial if you need more details.